# JWPlayer replay button doesn't work on iPhone iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7, jwplayer, jwplayer6

When video finishes playing on iPhone iOS7, the JWPlayer's replay button appears on video, but clicking it doesn't replay the video from the begining again. It just shows the video with player control at the end and last frame of video visible in iPhone's media player (see attached screenshot).

Here is a link:
http://repos.saeidmohadjer.com/sandbox/jwplayer_basic.php

[image: Attached is a screenshot that shows the viewport after replay button is clicked]

Answer (score 1):

This is something that happens in iOS7 in a  tag as well. You can test here - http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/formats/

After the video has played through and you try it play it again, it takes two presses (or "clicks") on the video to start playing again from the beginning.

I originally had thought this was a JW Player bug because I discovered this same issue during testing, but then I tested a plain  tag and had the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by a "tag"? 

Also it takes three "clicks", one on JWPlayer's replay button and two on iOS media player's play button. Who would figure that out?!!

Comment: Also I noticed that after replaying video via multiple "clicks", it's impossible to pause the video!

Comment: I mean a direct video in html5. Look at - http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/formats/, same thing happens.

Comment: This problem doesn't happen with embeded youtube videos, but embeded youtube videos don't automatically close the iphone media player when video ends playing as the jwplayer does. Here is an example: http://repos.saeidmohadjer.com/sandbox/youtube_responsive_no_js.php

Comment: I tried the first video (mp4) and I see no problem there, but that video doesn't show a replay button after playing has ended so I don't see why you are comparing these examples with the case here. The problem with jwplayer is only related to "REPLAY" button.

Comment: Yes, the player closes after playback has completed. This is the same thing as essentially pressing "done" when a video is playing. Try to press "done" on the single mp4 example and then try to re open it and play it again and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I see, but the big difference is that if you watch mp4 example all the way to the end and press "done" and try to reopen it, it will play immediately which is correct behavior (no extra click needed at all), but with jwplayer same thing requires three clicks!

Comment: Yes, we are detecting the complete. I can pass this along to our team. I hope Apple can fix this natively, as well, though.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I will appreciate it if you let me know when your team makes a change to improve the usability on iOS7. We are using jwplayer on a high traffic website and getting complaints from users regarding this.

Comment: No problem, any time.